# How to fill in a field conditionally in access based on two other fields in two different tables?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have two queries one based on estimated data and one with real date. I want to create a table merging these two query tables with selecting the real data when available and when not using the estimated data.   How would you do this within Access?

The Query data tables are:
tblRevenueConsulidatedByHE
fields
•   Date
•   HourEnding
•   kWh
tblSCADAConsulidatedByHE
fields
•   Date
•   HourEnding
•   kWh

Comment: Have you tried the make table button with a query?  Once the tables are created, you can use query wizard or query design to design what you want.  Then while in design view, query tools will offer a query type.  Make Table, Append Table, Update Table are all there.

Comment: Also here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638587%28v=office.12%29.aspx Look at the heading "Action Queries"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a create table query, for each conditional field use an IIF statement:

```
IIF(not isnull([RealDataFieldName]),[RealDataFieldName],[estimatedDataFieldName])
```